# strange mysql insert error

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary

I'm trying to insert dict values into database. But i'm getting error .[here is my dictionary](http://dpaste.com/642178/). I'm using this code .

```
       `cols = filter_dict.keys()
        vals = filter_dict.values()
        ("INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s)", [cols, vals])
`
```

When I only print this query `("INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s)", [cols, vals])`. 
I'm getting following output.
    `('INSERT INTO table (%s) VALUES (%s)', [['cinematography', 'name', 'producer', 'caption',  'studio', 'editing'], ['Venkat Prasad', '100% Love', 'Bunny Vasu', '', '100% Love Poster.jpg', 'Chandra Sekhar T Ramesh,Hari Prasad']])`

But When I execute this query I"m getting strange output.
 `the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'table (("\'cinematography\'", "\'name\`

Why execute query adding `\' to each columns?? Can any one help me? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes are likely due to your debugger. Are you running your code in the interactive prompt?

Anyway, the *actual* problems are:

- `table` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html). You should put `table` in backticks.
- If your table contains more than one column, you need to have multiple `%s` and multiple values.

For example:

```
"INSERT INTO `table` (%s, %s, &s) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
```

You will also need to change `(cols, vals)` to list the individual values.

```
(cols[0], cols[1], cols[2] , vals[0], vals[1], vals[2])
```

---

I'd also *strongly* suggest that you try to find a better name for your table, preferably one that:

1) describes what sort of data the table contains and

2) isn't a reserved word

Comment: @user559744: The error is similar but actually if you look closely, you will see that it is slightly different.

Comment: I have no idea. I'm confused.

Comment: Dictionary keys and values are dynamic.

Comment: @user559744: Then you will need to construct the query dynamically too.